# TYPO3 - caching issue - more than just the edited page gets "flushed"

Tags: caching, typo3, settings, typo3-6.2.x

I have a very simple and fresh TYPO3 (6.2.12) setup on my local machine (using xampp). I want to reproduce/solve an issue with caching. The issue is as follows: if I edit and save a page via the TYPO3 backend, not only the cache entry of the actual edited page gets flushed, it also flushes the cache entries of other (not edited) pages.

I'm running XAMPP (3.2.2) and I'm using TYPO3 in Version 6.2.12 which is properly installed. I didn't add any extensions manually so far.

I did create 2 simple pages in the TYPO3 backend. Let's call them site A and site B. When I both view them in the browser, they get cached properly. (I look it up in the 'cf_cache_pages' database. At this stage I have both pages cached (as wanted).

BUT: if I now edit site A in TYPO3 backend and press save, it deletes both my entries in the 'cf_cache_pages' db. Therefore, the cache of both pages has been flushed while only site A has been edited and actually should be flushed.

If I have both pages cached and only edit site A, I'd expect only site A to be cache cleared.  In fact however, both pages get flushed.

Is this supposed behaviour? And how can I eliminate it? Because I don't want unedited pages to be cache cleared every time I save changes on other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your configuration and your data it might be correct to clear other caches than the current page.

If you edit the `pages` record or typoscript record of a parent page it might be necessary to clear caches from subpages.
If you change records all pages where these records are used may need a cache clearing (especially pages with a plugin to display them)

Also be aware: if you are logged in to the BE, no page will be cached at all.

Comment: Thank you so far. Are you sure no pages will be cached if I'm logged in to the Backend? Because they appear in the mentioned database file if I load them the first time while I'm logged in. Maybe this is only true for newer TYPO3 versions?

Comment: there should be no cached pages for calls from your browser, where you are logged in. Calls from another browser or another 'private' instance could create cached data

Comment: this is weird then @Bernd Wilke. I even tried it with 2 version now (typo 3-6.2.12 and typo 3-9.5.3). I'm logged in at the backend and watching the page in the same browser (chrome) and it creates cached data for me (visible in the 'cf_cache_pages' DB).

So far it actually seems to work the way I want it with version 9.5.3. I created the same 2 pages, cached both, edited and saved only one of the pages and that one was cleared from cache while the other stayed (as supposed, in my case). Will do further testing if it actually works, but still need a solution, why it doesn't with 6.2.12

Comment: Why are your TYPO3 versions so old? Try latest 6.2 may your problem is solved. Better use supportet versions 8 or 9.

Comment: Latest free available version of 6.2 even is not the latest version. But that would cost you money: ELTS